# mysql: get daily average price of product table with version

Tags: mysql

my products table :

```
ProductId(inc.key) | Price | VersionCreatedDate | MainProductId
1                  | 15    | 1-11-2016          | 1
2                  | 20    | 1-11-2016          | 2
3                  | 30    | 1-11-2016          | 3
4                  | 10    | 2-11-2016          | 1 -> mainProductId 1 changed price(-5$)
5                  | 20    | 3-11-2016          | 3 -> mainProductId 3 changed price(-10$) 
6                  | 30    | 4-11-2016          | 3 -> mainProductId 3 changed price(+10$)
```

I want to display the output as like this

```
Date      | AvgPrice 
1-11-2016 | 21.67  ((15+20+30)/3) 
2-11-2016 | 20     ((10+20+30)/3)
3-11-2016 | 16.67  ((10+20+20)/3)
4-11-2016 | 20     ((10+20+30)/3)
```

How do I get the output with sql code?

Comment: I don't understand this at all. What does the `MainProductId` column mean, and how are you getting those other prices from it?

Comment: Row  is added when price changed. I am using  Main Product id  for group product. Every product has a mainProductId. Every version has a productid.

Comment: It might be possible to do this with SQL, but it will be complicated. It would almost certainly be easier in an application language like PHP or Python that processes the result.

Comment: If you do it in a real programming language, you can create a dictionary that maps each product to its price on the current date, and update it as you loop through the results, then calculate the average for all the products.

Comment: But big databases. product count is 100.000. how do i do php ?

Comment: You'll have the same size problem in SQL, because it will need to create an intermediate table with all the results of combining previous days with the current day.

Comment: I understand. But is there another way with sql query?

Comment: One more problem is your date format. You can't compare them without reformatting.

Comment: VersionCreatedDate's type is datetime

Comment: It sure doesn't look like one

Comment: @user3695826 You need to join the main table with a table that has all the dates in it. Then you need to join the table with itself, for each date and main product ID, finding the most recent row with that product ID in `mainProductId` or `productId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `calendar` table with all dates you need. And you have a `main_products` table with `MainProductId` as primary/unique key. The following query should return average prices for every day in october 2016.

```
select sub.date, avg(sub.Price) as Price
from (
    select 
        c.date,
        m.MainProductId,
        (
            select p.Price
            from products
            where p.MainProductId = m.MainProductId
              and p.VersionCreatedDate < c.date + interval 1 day
            order by p.VersionCreatedDate desc
            limit 1
        ) as Price
    from callendar c
    cross join main_products m
    where c.date between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-31'
) sub
group by sub.date
order by sub.date
```

The subquery (derived table aliased as `sub`) returns a combination of all dates in the range and all "main products" from the `main_products` table. The recent price each "main product" for a specific date is calculated in the subselect (correlated subquery in the SELECT clause) using ORDER BY and LIMIT 1. This allows us to group the subquery result by date and calculate the average price per date.

It is even possible to eliminate the derived table and hope that mysql can use an index to GROUP BY date instead of working on a temp table:

```
select c.date, avg((
        select p.Price
        from products
        where p.MainProductId = m.MainProductId
          and p.VersionCreatedDate < c.date + interval 1 day
        order by p.VersionCreatedDate desc
        limit 1
    )) as Price
from callendar c
cross join main_products m
where c.date between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-31'
group by c.date
order by c.date
```

I have no clue if that query can be executed effiently (especially if mysql can). You should however have at least the following indexes: callendar(date), products(MainProductId, VersionCreatedDate)